# Search for a text in a video (text is from the images, not the speech)

Tags: video

I'd like to be able to search for a text in a video. E.g., if a video frame contains the text "Interactive", then I'd like the solution to point to that frame if I search for this word:

[image]

([image source](https://youtu.be/KcELPpdN770?si=iwa-GWdvS1zjw0XG&t=5))

How can  I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I found a tool that can run on Linux that does what you want! If you don't have a Raspberry Pi or a Linux PC, you can use a Kali Linux virtual machine inside VirtualBox.

Just follow the instructions here. :)
[Video-OCR](https://pypi.org/project/video-ocr/)